# Convert $\frac{1+ \sqrt{3i} }{1- \sqrt{3i} }$ to polar form

Tags: complex-numbers, polar-coordinates

How do I convert $\frac{1+ \sqrt{3i} }{1- \sqrt{3i} }$ to polar form? I came across it [in this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1059673/complex-number-calculation) but I don't know much about complex numbers and have no idea how to figure out $\theta$.

Comment: Is the _i_ inside or outside the square root sign?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** $\arg(xz)=\arg(x)+\arg(z)$ which (setting $z=\frac{y}x$ and rearranging) yields:
$$\arg\left(\frac{y}x\right)=\arg(y)-\arg(x)$$
So it is only necessary to calculate the argument of $1+\sqrt{3}i$ and its conjugate (which has argument equal to the negative of that of $1+\sqrt{3}i$), then take their difference.

Comment: Ohhh... that's much better than what I was trying which was just getting the original fraction into $a + bi$.

Comment: @Rene Doing that actually wouldn't be *too* bad; if you multiply through by the denominator, you're just trying to solve:
$$(a+bi)(1-\sqrt{3}i)=1+\sqrt{3}i$$
and after you separate into real and imaginary parts, you'd get two linear equations:
$$a-\sqrt{3}b=1$$
$$\sqrt{3}a+b=\sqrt{3}$$
which is easy enough.